# How to extract info from original dataframe after doing some analysis on it?

Tags: python, pandas

So I had a dataframe and I had to do some cleansing to minimize the duplicates. In order to do that I created a dataframe that had instead of 40 only 8 of the original columns. Now I have two columns I need for further analysis from the original dataframe but they would mess with the desired outcome if I used them in my previous analysis. Anyone have any idea on how to "extract" these columns based on the new "clean" dataframe I have?

Comment: I have a feeling what you need is `pd_new = pd_clean[['col1', 'col2']].copy()`

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the new "clean" dataframe with the other two variables by using the indexes. Let me use a pratical example. Suppose the "initial" dataframe, called "df", is:

```
df
    name    year    reports location
0   Jason   2012    4       Cochice
1   Molly   2012    24      Pima
2   Tina    2013    31      Santa Cruz
3   Jake    2014    2       Maricopa
4   Amy     2014    3       Yuma
```

while the "clean" dataframe is:

```
d1
    year    location    
0   2012    Cochice     
2   2013    Santa Cruz  
3   2014    Maricopa
```

The remaing columns are saved in dataframe "d2" ( `d2 = df[['name','reports']]` ):

```
d2
    name    reports
0   Jason   4
1   Molly   24
2   Tina    31
3   Jake    2
4   Amy     3
```

By using the inner join on the indexes  `d1.merge(d2, how = 'inner' left_index= True, right_index = True)`  you get the following result:

```
    name    year    reports location
0   Jason   2012    4       Cochice
2   Tina    2013    31      Santa Cruz
3   Jake    2014    2       Maricopa
```

Comment: ok that seem great. any idea on how to keep the same index throughout because it is reset to start from zero each time.

Comment: You can save your index in another column with the commnad `df['new'] = df.index` and then apply inner join using the column "new" as key.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new dataframe with the specified columns;

```
import pandas
#If your columns are named a,b,c,d etc
df1 = df[['a','b']]

#This will extract columns 0, to 2 based on their index 
#[remember that pandas indexes columns from zero!
df2 = df.iloc[:,0:2]
```

If you could, provide a sample piece of data, that'd make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: to give you an idea the new dataframe is [1000,8] and the old was [5000,40]. so basically I need these 1000 rows matched with the values of the old dataframe.Unfortunately the data might be sensitive so I cannot post them

Comment: I understand, can you post redacted information then?

Comment: so basically i need the 3rd and 4th column for my new dataset but the only for the 1000 "clean" values.

Comment: assuming you've created a "clean" dataframe, using ```extracteddataframe = cleandataframe.iloc[:,3:5]``` will take columns ```[3,4]``` from ```cleandataframe```. Remember that indexing starts at zero.

Comment: that will not work. keep in mind the clean dataframe does not include the columns 3,4 from the picture because it would mess with the result. So basically with the new dataframe somehow i need to match some of the info to the old and extract the 1000 rows i need from the two columns